# Java, remove PDF password and return byte array

Tags: java, binary, pdfbox

Im trying to remove the password from a pdf document and returning the bytes.

```
PDDocument pddocument = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(Binary_PDF.getContentBytes()), sPDF_Password);
test1 = Arrays.toString(Binary_PDF.getContentBytes());
pddocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
PDStream pdStream = new PDStream(pddocument);
test2 = Arrays.toString(pdStream.toByteArray());
Binary_PDF = new emds.util.Base64Binary(pdStream.toByteArray());
```

test1 is filled (array contains values)

test2 is empty (array contains no values)

How can I fix this issue? It's just the java PDFBox.

Comment: `new PDStream(pddocument)` "Creates a new empty PDStream object" according to the API docs

Comment: But I'm creating a new PDStream? Line 4?

Comment: I don't know the API - i'm just [conveying what the docs say] (https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/common/PDStream.html#PDStream-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-). I'm guessing you have to process it before it's filled

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
PDDocument pddocument = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(Binary_PDF.getContentBytes()), sPDF_Password);
pddocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pddocument.save(out);
pddocument.close();
Binary_PDF = new emds.util.Base64Binary(out.toByteArray());
```